# How do you make the game end when the main player collides with an image (obstacle)?

Tags: python, pygame

```
import math
import random
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import sys



def events():
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT or (event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_ESCAPE):
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()


pygame.init()
W = 700
H = 400
updater = pygame.time.Clock()
display = pygame.display.set_mode((700, 400))
pygame.display.set_caption("Skating_Game")
x = y = 0

surface = pygame.image.load("man2.png")
pygame.display.set_icon(surface)

class player:
    def __init__(self, velocity, maxJumpRange):
        self.velocity = velocity
        self.maxJumpRange = maxJumpRange

    def setLocation(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.xVelocity = 0
        self.jumping = False
        self.jumpCounter = 0
        self.falling = True

    def keys(self):
        k = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if k[K_LEFT]:
            self.xVelocity = -self.velocity
        elif k[K_RIGHT]:
            self.xVelocity = self.velocity
        else:
            self.xVelocity = 0

        if k[K_SPACE] and not self.jumping and not self.falling:
            self.jumping = True
            self.jumpCounter = 0

    def move(self):
        self.x += self.xVelocity

        if self.jumping:
            self.y -= self.velocity
            self.jumpCounter += 1
            if self.jumpCounter  == self.maxJumpRange:
                self.jumping = False
                self.falling = True
        elif self.falling:
             if self.y <= H - 60 and self.y + self.velocity >= H - 60:
                 self.y = H - 60
                 self.falling = False
             else:
                self.y += self.velocity

    def draw(self):
        display = pygame.display.get_surface()
        character = pygame.image.load("man3.png").convert_alpha()
        display.blit(character, (self.x, self.y - 100))

        #pygame.draw.circle(display, (255, 255, 255), (self.x, self.y - 25), 25, 0)
    def do(self):
        self.keys()
        self.move()
        self.draw()

P = player(3, 50)
P.setLocation(350, 0)
BLACK = (  0,   0,   0)

g=0
font = pygame.font.SysFont("Plump", 30)

obstacle = pygame.image.load("obstacle.png").convert_alpha()


background = pygame.image.load("Road.png").convert()
x = 0
while True:


    events()

    rel_x = x % background.get_rect().width
    display.blit(background, (rel_x - background.get_rect().width,0))
    if rel_x < 700:
        display.blit(background, (rel_x, 0))
    x -= 1
    g += 0.01
    pygame.draw.rect(display, (255,255,255,128), [rel_x, 275, 150, 50])
    display.blit(obstacle, (rel_x, 250))
    text = font.render("Score: "+str(int(g)), True, (255, 255, 255))
    display.blit(text, (0,0))


    P.do()
    if P.rect.collidepoint(self.x,self.y):
            pygame.quit()
    pygame.display.update()
    updater.tick(200)
```

So if the player collides with the obstacle image the game should stop. How do i do this? I have made a class for the player and the obstacle is just an image which is constantly moving.

I was thinking maybe I could track the x and y coordinate of the player and obstacle and when their radius overlaps the game could stop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working (simplified) version of your program with some comments. You have to create rects for the obstacle and the player and then check if the rects collide with the help of the [`colliderect`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.colliderect) method.

```
import sys
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *


pygame.init()
W = 700
H = 400
updater = pygame.time.Clock()
display = pygame.display.set_mode((700, 400))

PLAYER_IMAGE = pygame.Surface((30, 50))
PLAYER_IMAGE.fill(pygame.Color('dodgerblue1'))

class Player:

    def __init__(self, x, y, velocity, maxJumpRange):
        self.velocity = velocity
        self.maxJumpRange = maxJumpRange
        self.image = PLAYER_IMAGE  # Give the player an image.
        # Create a rect with the size of the PLAYER_IMAGE and
        # pass the x, y coords as the topleft argument.
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=(x, y))
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.xVelocity = 0
        self.jumping = False
        self.jumpCounter = 0
        self.falling = True

    def keys(self):
        k = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if k[K_LEFT]:
            self.xVelocity = -self.velocity
        elif k[K_RIGHT]:
            self.xVelocity = self.velocity
        else:
            self.xVelocity = 0

        if k[K_SPACE] and not self.jumping and not self.falling:
            self.jumping = True
            self.jumpCounter = 0

    def move(self):
        self.x += self.xVelocity

        if self.jumping:
            self.y -= self.velocity
            self.jumpCounter += 1
            if self.jumpCounter  == self.maxJumpRange:
                self.jumping = False
                self.falling = True
        elif self.falling:
             if self.y >= H - 160:  # Simplified a little.
                 self.y = H - 160
                 self.falling = False
             else:
                self.y += self.velocity
        # Update the position of the rect, because it's
        # used for the collision detection.
        self.rect.topleft = self.x, self.y

    def draw(self, display):
        # Just draw the image here.
        display.blit(self.image, (self.x, self.y))

    def do(self):
        self.keys()
        self.move()


player = Player(350, 0, 3, 50)

obstacle = pygame.Surface((150, 50))
obstacle.fill(pygame.Color('sienna1'))
# Create a rect with the size of the obstacle image.
obstacle_rect = obstacle.get_rect()

g = 0
x = 0
FPS = 60  # Cap the frame rate at 60 or 30 fps. 300 is crazy.
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT or (event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_ESCAPE):
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    # --- Update the game ---
    player.do()
    rel_x = x % display.get_width()
    x -= 7
    g += 0.01
    obstacle_rect.topleft = rel_x, 250  # Update the position of the rect.

    # --- Draw everything ---
    display.fill((30, 30, 30))
    display.blit(obstacle, (rel_x, 250))
    if g > 30:
        display.blit(obstacle, (rel_x+350, 250))

    # Check if the obstacle rect and the player's rect collide.
    if obstacle_rect.colliderect(player.rect):
        print("Game over!")  # And call pygame.quit and sys.exit if you want.

    # Draw the image/surface of the player onto the screen.
    player.draw(display)
    # Draw the actual rects of the objects (for debugging).
    pygame.draw.rect(display, (200, 200, 0), player.rect, 2)
    pygame.draw.rect(display, (200, 200, 0), obstacle_rect, 2)

    pygame.display.update()
    updater.tick(FPS)
```

Comment: Load your images before the while loop starts, because it's slow to load them from the hard disk every frame.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Pygame rectangles include a [collidepoint and colliderect](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.colliderect) method that allows you to check to see if something intersects with a rectangle. So you could have rectangles drawn beneath the obstacle and check to see if the player's coordinates intersect with the rectangle. Like this:

```
if self.rect.collidepoint(self.x,self.y):
    pygame.quit()
```

Comment: i am new to pygame how would i add a rectangle beneath the obstacle?

Comment: Draw the rectangle the exact same as the picture pretty much. Use pygame.draw.rect() to create a rectangle and update it's coordinates just like you updated the pictures coordinates

Comment: if self.rect.collidepoint(self.x,self.y):
    pygame.quit()
when i add this to my loop it says self is not defined

Comment: If you put it in the loop like that, you should call the player class, which I believe you already did and named it p. it would be p.rect.collidepoint(self.x,self.y):

Comment: I already tried that but then the new error is AttributeError: 'player' object has no attribute 'rect

Comment: Can you edit the original so I can see your updated code?

Comment: I updated it. I would be really grateful if you can help me out. thx